# Decodable wrapper for standard nested JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift, decode

I am consuming an api that follows a fairly similar response structure:

```
{
    "error": "string item",
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "users" : [
              {
                "id": "20001",
                "firstname": "John",
                "lastname" : "Smith",
                "address": "123 king street",
                "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "0412345678"
              },
              {
                "id": "20002",
                "firstname": "Jack",
                "lastname": "Master",
                "address": "123 rainbow road",
                "email": "jack.master@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "0412345678"
              }
        ]
    }
}
```

The api returns a different result based on the endpoint. I want to create a standard decodable json response struct. Then I just create a new decodeable struct for each different result type.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
struct JSONResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var error: String
    var success: Bool
    var result: T
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do

```
struct User: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var email: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case users
    }
    
    enum UserKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, firstName = "firstname", lastName = "lastname", email, mobile
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let nestedContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: UserKeys.self, forKey: .users)

        id = try nestedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        firstName = try nestedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try nestedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        email = try nestedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
    }
    
}
```

Then decode a number of different responses in a fashion like this

```
let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode(JSONResponse<User>.self, from: responseData!)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/chipjarred/JSONRPC.git) that implements JSONRPC client and server, so I had to solve this exact problem, though perhaps more generically.  I did it by defining an AnyJSON type and extensions for containers in the container types for Codable.  You may find my solution useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, you have multiple `User` objects, so you'd need some kind of container:

```
struct Users: Decodable {
   var users: [User]
}
```

`User` also doesn't need to be this complicated:

```
struct User: Decodable {
   var id: String
   var firstName: String
   var lastName: String
   var email: String
}
```

and then decode as:

```
let users = JSONDecoder().decode(JSONResponse<Users>.self, from: responseData)
```